# Why boost ini_parser does not work with relative path?

Tags: c++, path, relative-path, ini

There is ini parsing code

```
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini("file.ini", pt);
```

In ini_parser.hpp exception throwed.

```
// ini_parser.hpp - Exeption throwed
//
Ptree &container = section ? *section : local;
typename Str::size_type eqpos = line.find(Ch('='));
if (eqpos == Str::npos)
    BOOST_PROPERTY_TREE_THROW(ini_parser_error(
        "'=' character not found in line", "", line_no));
```

But if I use absolute path for file.ini it works good.

How can I use relative path?

Comment: maybe the "current directory" is not what you expect, so entering the absolute path points to a different file.ini.

Comment: Operating system? Directory Layout? The actual command line you call? The actual exception message?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I bet the message is _"ini_parser_error: '=' character not found in line XXX"_ (just a guess :))

Answer (score 0):

No doubt your working directory isn't where you think it is.

The working directory might not contain the `file.ini` file or it contains another file by that name, but no valid ini file contents

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, with the information provided, that you don't have the current working directory you expect. Which compiler/environment are you using, and how did you specify the working directory for your program ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case that was ini encoding UTF-8 with BOM instead of plain UTF-8